# Backbone embedded collection event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a model (see Delegation) made of basic attributes (name, activity) and one collection (members).

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lafare/19up4c8e/)

The fetch method update the model and trigger a sync event on it - but I would like to be notified when the embedded collection is synced (ie in a real case to render a view when the inner collection is synced).

I tried this

```
this.listenTo(this.get('members'),'sync',function(){...}
```

but the corresponding event never fires.

What is the proper way to have it triggered?

Answer (score 0):

> When you execute the `fetch` function of **Backbone**, it returns a
>   [PROMISE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can use the function then to launch a function at the
>   moment the `fetch` is finished, you can also use the `catch` for when
>   it fails.

### **For example:**

```
this.model = new Backbone.Model()
this.model.url ="example"
this.model.fetch().then((data) => { 
    console.log("succes: " + data); // Finished the fetch successfully 
  }).catch((data) =>{ 
    console.log("error: " + data); // The fetch ended in error
  })
```

### For your code:

You can use it in this part Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch or if your fetch function returns a Promise, use it when calling the fetch of the model.

Comment: Hello javimovi,

Thank you for taking time to reply to my question.

However, I'm not sure I understand your answer and how could the promise be used to trigger the event?

Could you give me a full code example or modify the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code that fetches the collection, hence `sync` is not triggered on the collection.
You should do `delegation1.get('members').fetch()`. For this to work, the collection should have it's own URL as well.

Comment: Hello TJ,

Thank you, if I understand well, calling fetch on the model containing the collection isn't enough to fetch properly the collection itself?

I've just one URL returning both the collection content and the additional parameters (as in the fiddle)  
var jsonData = {
    name: "delegation_2",
    activity: "design",
    members: [
      {firstname: "John", lastname: "DOE"},
      {firstname: "Jean", lastname: "Dupont"}
    ]
  }; 
Should I deal with this in the parse method or there is a better technic?

Comment: " calling fetch on the model containing the collection isn't enough to fetch properly the collection itself" - yes, because backbone doesn't support nested structures out of the box. If your application needs such capabilities a lot, maybe look into backbone plugins such as http://backbonerelational.org/.
If you only want minimal capabilities, you can override the `fetch/save/destroy` or `sync` (for all of them) and `parse` to add your custom collection handling -
something like `save(){ //your code here; Backbone.model.prototype.save.call(this, arguments);}`

Comment: Or just keep it simple and deal with model only: inside model's `parse` make a collection and add as a model attribute, then override the models `toJSON()` method, call `toJSON()` on the collection, add it to the rest of model attributes and return the combined data structure.
In this case your backend for the model should be able to handle model+collection data...

Comment: Thank you for the directions, I'll give a try to the second solution.
Backbonerelational is over-weighted regarding my needs.